# Why are 093/8 IP adresses in both US and Europe?

Tags: ip-address, ipv4

According to [this page](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xhtml) of the IANA website, the IP addresses 093/8 are allocated to RIPE NCC (European network).

However, when I use websites to locate IP ([like this one](http://www.ip-address.org/lookup/ip-locator.php?track=93.184.216.34)), they tell me that 93.184.216.34 is in the USA.
So I have a little bit of trouble understanding why is this RIPE NCC IP address located in the US.

Also, 93.184.216.34 is the IP address for [example.com](http://example.com/), which seems to be a special case, but I have the same issue with [93.184.216.255](http://www.ip-address.org/lookup/ip-locator.php?track=93.184.216.255). However [93.192.16.255](http://www.ip-address.org/lookup/ip-locator.php?track=93.192.16.255) seems to be in Germany.

Are the locators wrong? Or 093/8 is not entirely allocated to RIPE NCC, which who contradict the IANA webpage above? Or maybe, IP addresses allocated to RIPE NCC can be in the US?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The address block 93.0.0.0/8 is allocated to RIPE NCC.

From this block, RIPE NCC has allocated a couple of smaller blocks to Edgecast, namely 93.184.208.0/24 through 93.184.219.0/24 and 93.184.220.0/22.

Once allocated, Edgecast is free to use these blocks wherever they see fit.

Comment: The IP addresses allocated to the RIRs are not as regional as what I thought :-)

Answer (score 0):

093/8 is not always the same as 93/8. A leading Zero in an IP address can be a valid, though uncommon, way of noting that an address is expressed in octal (base-8).

[wikipedia: dot-decimal notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-decimal_notation)

[IETF: Text representation of IP Addresses](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-main-ipaddr-text-rep-02)

Comment: 093 is not a valid octal number.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt Well there is that.